# TextView not Ellipsizing

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

I have this TextView

```
<TextView
    style="@style/ellipsize"
    android:text="@string/alphabet"
    android:id="@+id/class_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/is_alt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




<style name="ellipsize">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:maxEms">5</item>m>
    <item name="android:maxLength">5</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

However the text doesn't ellipsize, it just stops. E.g. the above give just abcde, rather than abcde...

What have I got wrong?

Comment: I've heard `android:maxLines` does not work properly. Try `android:singleLine`.

Comment: That's the same too, just stops after 5 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a particular width to your textView like 50 dip or 60dip. If you restrict the textView to 5 chars it will show only 5 chars. The main logic for ellipsize is if your text is too long to be accomodated in the text view then only it will ellipsize. Remove maxlength and maxEMS and try givinga longer text after assigning the textview a fixed width.

Comment: The only issue with that is I can't have a fixed width on the TextView. The end output I need is 2 TextViews horizontally, the one of the right to always wrap_content, and the one of the left to just fill the rest of the parent width, and ellipsize if the text is longer. Could I get that using LinearLayout maybe?

Comment: UPDATE: Got it working. I couldn't have a fixed width but I used leftOf and rightOf to get it working how I needed.